# Mean of a Chi Square

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given that the residual sum of squares (RSS) follows Chi Square distribution.
$RSS ∼ σ^2χ^2_{n-2}$

When I ran a program for n = 10, 50 (n=sample size) I noticed that the 'mean' of the RSS over
1,000 simulation runs is close to n − 2.

I want to know the reason why the mean is always close to n-2?

Comment: Because $E(X) = \nu$ for $X \sim Chisq(\nu).$ See Wilipedia on 'chi squared distribution'. (I guess you simulated with $\sigma = 1.$)

Answer (score 0):

If $X\sim\chi_{(n-k)}^2$, then it is well-known that $E[X] = n-k$. In your case, $$\frac{\text{RSS}}{\sigma^2} = X \sim\chi_{(n-2)}^2$$
and hence $E[X] = n-2$.

I think you are trying to say that you have
$$\sigma^2 E[X] = \sigma^2(n-2).$$

So I'm guess that you have $E[\text{RSS}/\sigma^2]$ and the mean ***is*** $n-2$, or as the others have pointed out, you have $E[\text{RSS}]$ and the mean is $\sigma^2(n-2)$, but since since $\sigma^2\approx 1$, then the mean is close to $n-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for "simple" regression model ($y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x+\epsilon)$, you get $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{Y}_i - Y_i)^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi_{(n-2)}^2 \stackrel{d}= \Gamma(1/2, (n-2)/2)$. So, the expected value is given by $\frac{(n-2)/2}{1/2}=n-2.$ For a model with $p$ parametrs ($\beta$) you will get $n-p$.

So, $RSS = \sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i - \hat{Y_i})^2 = \sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i - \hat{Y_i})^2/\sigma^2$, then $E(RSS)=\sigma^2 (n-2).$

as @BruceET. mentioned in a comment, your $\sigma^2$ probably equals $1$.